# Rearrangement of Nested Sums

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following nested sum that I need to be able to rearrange to show it is equal to the following, however I am unsure on the intermediate steps to prove the equality.

I want to show:
$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i} (1-t)^{n-i}t^i \left( \sum_{j=0}^{i} {i \choose j} (1-\tau)^{i-j} \tau^j \mathbf{P_j}  \right)  =  \sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i} (1-\tau t)^{n-i} (\tau t)^i \mathbf{P_i}$.

Where $\mathbf{P_0} , \cdots , \mathbf{P_n}$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and ${n \choose i}$ and ${i \choose j}$ are binomial coefficents.

Comment: In the nested sum, should it be ${i \choose j}$?

Comment: Sorry it should be, I'll edit that now